# Two inputs with seperate outputs to one model in Keras (Shared layers)

Tags: deep-learning, tf.keras

Is it possible in tensorflow.keras to have two inputs to the same conv layer and receive to outputs each corresponding to one of the inputs?(i.e: using the same filters for two parallel paths)

Answer (score 0):

I think I found The answer [here](https://keras.io/guides/functional_api/#shared-layers).

```
In1 = tensorflow.keras.layers.Input(shape=(img_size, img_size, num_channels), name="in1")
In2 = tensorflow.keras.layers.Input(shape=(img_size, img_size, num_channels), name="in2")
conv_layer1 = tensorflow.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=1, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding="same", strides=1, name="conv_1")
out1=conv_layer1(In1)
out2=conv_layer1 (In2)
```